# Include libraries with g++

Tags: c++, g++, xively

My cpp project uses these libraries:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <time.h>

#include <xively.h>
#include <xi_helpers.h>

#include <wiringPi.h>
```

The `wiringPi.h` is in `/home/pi/wiringPi/wiringPi` and the xively.h is in `/root/libxively/src/libxively`

Before I used the `xively.h` I could compile it with `g++ -o ilc ilc.cpp -lwiringPi`. I now tried `g++ -o ilc ilc.cpp -I/root/libxively/src/libxively -I/home/pi/wiringPi/wiringPi`. This doesnt work and reports an "undefined reference" for all the function calls of the wiringPi library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xively C library currently doesn't implement a high-level C++ wrapper.

You need to statically link with `libxively.a`.

Below are instructions which should get you started.

```sh
git clone --recursive https://github.com/xively/libxively
cd libxively/src
make
mkdir my_project
cd my_project
```

In `my_project`, create `main.cpp` with the following code:

```
#include "xively.h"
#include "xi_err.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define XI_FEED_ID 1234 // set Xively Feed ID (numerical, no quoutes
#define XI_API_KEY "INSER_YOUR_API_KEY" // set Xively API key (double-quoted string) 

int main() {

    xi_feed_t feed;
    memset( &feed, NULL, sizeof( xi_feed_t ) );

    feed.feed_id = XI_FEED_ID;
    feed.datastream_count = 2;

    feed.datastreams[0].datapoint_count = 1;
    xi_datastream_t* foo_datastream = &feed.datastreams[0];
    strcpy( foo_datastream->datastream_id, "foo" );
    xi_datapoint_t* current_foo = &foo_datastream->datapoints[0];

    feed.datastreams[1].datapoint_count = 1;
    xi_datastream_t* bar_datastream = &feed.datastreams[1];
    strcpy( bar_datastream->datastream_id, "bar" );
    xi_datapoint_t* current_bar = &bar_datastream->datapoints[0];

    // create the xively library context
    xi_context_t* xi_context
        = xi_create_context( XI_HTTP, XI_API_KEY, feed.feed_id );

    // check if everything works
    if( xi_context == NULL )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    xi_set_value_str( current_bar, "unknown" );

    xi_set_value_f32( current_foo, 0.123 );

    xi_feed_update(xi_context, &feed);

    return 0;
}
```

Now we can compile it and statically link with `libxively.a`:

```sh
g++ main.cpp ../obj/libxively.a -I../libxively/ -o ../bin/my_project
```

And running `../bin/my_project` should produce output like this:

```
% ../bin/my_project 
[222@xively.c] - Getting the comm layer...
[222@xively.c] - Getting the transport layer...
[222@xively.c] - Getting the data layer...
[231@xively.c] - Connecting to the endpoint...
[231@xively.c] - Sending data:
PUT /v2/feeds/1234.csv HTTP/1.1
Host: api.xively.com
User-Agent: libxively-posix/0.1.x-1a79892
Accept: */*
X-ApiKey: INSER_YOUR_API_KEY
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 25

foo,0.123000
bar,unknown

[231@xively.c] - Sent: 218
[231@xively.c] - Reading data...
[231@xively.c] - Received: 512
[231@xively.c] - Response:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 12:38:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 50
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Web Password"
X-Request-Id: 0a25d76545c371a2bd6ef368cc1859f1fd5abb9a
Set-Cookie: _pachcore_app_session=BAh7BkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTY4ZmU1NjUxMjhmNmI2MDlhN2E1ZDNkZmMyNjNhNGYwBjsAVA%3D%3D--9510f98ab1aa46a3978e06e41b2548280d4d2a63; domain=.xively.com; path=/; expires=Wed, 31-Jul-2013 12:38:00 GMT; HttpOnly

You do not have permission to access this resource
```

You now can insert the API key and feed ID and you should be all set.
To add the other library you mentioned, just add `-lwiringPi` to the compiler command line.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two different things:

- insertion of an include file (`-I` switch)
- linking with external library (`-l` switch)

You should keep the `-lwiringPi` switch in your command line, that is

```
 g++ -o ilc ilc.cpp -I/root/libxively/src/libxively -I/home/pi/wiringPi/wiringPi -lwiringPi
```

Comment: this returns `fatal error: xively.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Does it with the line I just wrote ?

Comment: Yor line returns five undefined references to functions of the xively library.

Comment: So now you should add the corresponding ``-l`` command to link with xively. propably something like ``-lxively``.

Comment: It returns `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxively`. When I downloaded the xively library with the git command I had to type `make all` which failed. Could this be the problem? [Here](https://github.com/xively/libxively) are the instructions (at "Get started").

Comment: I successfuly ran the `make all` comand. But I still don't know what the correct -l command is.

Comment: In some subdirectory of ``/root/libxively/...`` there should be a file named ``libxively.so`` or something. You should tell the compiler where to find this file by adding a ``-L/THE/DIR/OF/THE/SO/FILE`` to the command line. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078602/c-how-to-add-external-libraries

Comment: I can only find an .o file, but no .so files.

Comment: In that case ``g++ -o ilc ilc.cpp /path/to/xively.o  -I/root/libxively/src/libxively -I/home/pi/wiringPi/wiringPi -lwiringPi`` may write. Otherwise you should ask the maintainer of this xively thing, as I'm not sure it is correctly installed on your computer.