# How to update a xively feed in a C++ project

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, xively

I have a Raspberry Pi that reads sensor data and I would like to send it to a xively feed.

I figured out that I have to use either the [API](https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/data/write/multiple_datapoints_to_single_datastream/) or the [C library](https://github.com/xively/libxively). I [failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661058/include-libraries-with-g/17661392?noredirect=1) trying to use the library.

I would like to have something like this in my C++ program:

```
xively.update("sensor1",sensorvalue);
```

What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xively C library currently doesn't implement a high-level C++ wrapper.

You need to statically link with `libxively.a`.

I have just answered on the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661058/include-libraries-with-g/17700233#17700233).